# When will the next (3.8 or later) set of DBPedia dumps be available?

Tags: dbpedia

Is there an announced/expected timeframe when the next (after 3.7) set of DBPedia extraction dumps will be available? (Does the project have a target interval?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our target release date is late March. Expect an announcement on the dbpedia-discussion mailing list in the next few days. (I'm currently working for the DBpedia project at Freie Universität Berlin.)

EDIT: Some things take longer than expected... target release date moved from late March to late April. Sorry for the delay. By the way, yes, we have a target interval, and it's six months.

Join the DBpedia Mapping Sprin(g|t) 2012! The new and improved mappings will be used for the upcoming DBpedia 3.8 release.

EDIT 2: Took longer than expected, offers a lot more data than DBpedia 3.7 - [DBpedia 3.8](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38) is here.

Comment: Thanks, recently came across the new expanded dumps.